# Haxe sys.net.UdpSocket Error: Custom(std@socket_recv_from)

Tags: sockets, udp, haxe, openfl

I'm trying to make UDP connection with sys.net.UdpSocket library in Haxe.

Server: Node JS
Client: Haxe ()

```
var udpsocket:UdpSocket = new UdpSocket();
var addr:Address = new Address();
addr.host = new Host("127.0.0.1").ip;
addr.port = 36000;

while(true){
    try{
        var bf:Bytes = Bytes.alloc(2048);
        var length:Int = udpsocket.readFrom(bf, 0, bf.length, addr); // Error happens here
        var msg:String = bf.getString(0, length);
    }
    catch (e:Dynamic) {
        trace(e);
    }
}
```

At udpsocket.readFrom(..) line,

Program throws: **Custom(std@socket_recv_from)**

Answer (score 0):

According to **andyli** @ https://github.com/andyli/hxudp/issues/6#issuecomment-117970567 (bottom comment) UdpSocket is not implemented fully for neither neko or cpp targets.